# Why do I have to keep disconnecting and reconnecting the wired network every few seconds?

Tags: internet, ethernet, ip, lan, wired

This question would look similar to many but it's different. It's not about my network keeps disconnecting ! Let me explain the problem: I have a wired ipv4 network connection, and the network sign shows that my laptop is connected but the internet dies out in a few seconds or let's say becomes infinitely slowly but still connected. Every few seconds it happenes and if I just click "disconnect" and then "connect" again, instantly the internet is back and the same problem repeats every few seconds.

There's nothing wrong with:

(1) The internet network. because other computers are doing fine.

(2) My laptop, because it works perfectly when I use other networks, like at home or office.

My guess is that there's something wrong with my IP address, but it's just a guess. I am not an expert in these things so have no idea what actually is going on. Any help will be highly appreciated because this has made my life partially miserable.

---

**Edit # 1:**

Time: **15.57**, **Dec 4**, 2016, Naples Italy.

**Network Used:** **The home network** that doesn't have any issues.

---

@heynnema  pointed out that it could be a driver issue and suggested to include the output of "`sudo lshw -C network`" hence I am doing it, although I don't think it's a driver issue because the system works fine in any other network. By the way I should stress that right now I am posting the output from my home network (which works fine) as it's Sunday !

---

`someone@somewhere:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED

       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7900000-f79fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: bc:ee:7b:2e:e5:63
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.2 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff`

---

Further information: If I understood @Kyle H and @dr01 correctly, I think by static IP they meant (my lack of vocabulary not their clarity!) inserting IP and Netmask etc by hand in IPv4 settings, then yes I did exactly that:

"`Edit connection->Wired->Add->IPv4 settings->Manual->Add`"

Then I inserted the `Address, Netmask, Gateway, DNS Server` etc.

---

**Edit # 2:**

Time: **18.46**, **Dec 5**, 2016, Naples Italy.

**Network Used:** **The office network** that has the issue !

---

This is the output of `sudo lshw -C network` run from my **office network** that has the issues:

---

`someone@somewhere:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED

       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7900000-f79fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: bc:ee:7b:2e:e5:63
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.2 03/27/12 ip=172.16.7.149 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff`

---

**Note:** I have also tried to use **Automatic (DHCP)**, it didn't work, the network won't connect !

Comment: What if you take note of the IP, Gateway, and subnet mask that you are given from the DHCP server, and set your ip as static using that information for now until you can notify your sys admin?

Comment: You probably have a bad driver. Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo lshw -C network` and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I apologize for not updating or answering to any comments so far ! I won't be able to access that network until tomorrow (Monday) as my office remains closed during the weekends.

Comment: @heynnema I don't think it's a driver problem. Because the internet works like charm in any other network. But I will post the output of "`sudo lshw -C network`" for completeness. But please note that, I will be doing this from home and not from the same network where the problem actually is.

Comment: I noticed that you say you've set a static IP address. Any particular reason? Tell us what numbers you used. If you go to the network settings panel, IPv4 tab, try and change it from manual to automatic (dhcp), reboot, and see if it fixes your problem. I'd still like to see the `sudo lshw -C network` so I can check your driver for you. The "bad" drive exhibits symptoms like what you describe.

Comment: @ heynnema Hi, the reason for using static IP is that my institute provides us with a list of addresses that we can use, I chose one. By the way I have already updated my question with the output of `sudo lshw -C network` but using my home network, tomorrow I will update the question using the office network. But as it is related to driver so I guess it's irrelevant which network I use.. isn't it ? I will try the "automatic DHCP" thing tomorrow.

Comment: @ heynnema I have edited the question, please check **Edit 2**.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a flapping network connection when by mistake another user was assigned my IP address. So it might be a problem of IP address collision. If your IP address is statically set, change it; if you're using DHCP, try to renew your lease.

Edit: you say that your home network works fine. Then it's not a driver issue. You should check the problem with your network administrator at work/University (have him check if you need a static or DHCP address, on which subnet, etc).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @dr01 , "IP address collision", this is my suspicion too but unfortunately I don't know how to check who else is using my IP, can you suggest a way ? " If your IP address is statically set", what do you mean by that ? I set my network details by going to "Edit connection-->Wired-->Add-->IPv4 settings-->Manual-->Add" and then adding "Address, Netmask, Gateway, DNS server". "if you're using DHCP, try to renew your lease", sorry but I am not familiar with these vocabulary :) please explain.